# Coloring of surfaces in 3D with Mathematica

Tags: image, colors, wolfram-mathematica

I have a cloud of points in 3D. It is easy to plot them with Mathematica with ListPlot3D function. The coloring is a bit difficult for me. I would like to get a result like this:

```
SphericalPlot3D[
 1 + Sin[-5 \[Phi]] Sin[-5 \[Theta]]/10, {\[Theta], 
  0, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#6] &), Mesh -> None, 
 PlotPoints -> 30, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

So that color would show the radial distance from the center. Is it possible to do it? I also have very near spherical cloud of data, more precisely spherical-like cap with bulges.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
nPoints = 10^3;
SeedRandom[7];
data = CoordinateTransformData["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", "Mapping", #] & /@ 
  Transpose[{1 + RandomReal[{-0.15, 0.15}, nPoints], RandomReal[{0, Pi}, nPoints], RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}, nPoints]}];

ListSurfacePlot3D[data, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][EuclideanDistance[{0, 0, 0},{#1, #2, #3}]] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image: plot]